# Check last line of file and if it is the same do not write a new line

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to check the last line in a file, if its the same text as the text i am getting from a website, it should not write a new line with the text. If the file is empty it should write a line, which works already.

```
DATA = requests.get("...", {"...": "...", "...": "..."}).json()
CURRENT_DATA = str("{}: {}\n".format(DATA["time"], DATA["price"]))

FILE = open("SPRIT.log", "a+")
try:
  FILE.readlines()[0]
except:
  FILE.write("{}: {}\n".format(DATA["time"], DATA["price"]))
FILE_STORED_DATA = FILE.readlines()[-1]
if CURRENT_DATA != STORED_DATA:
  FILE.write("{}: {}\n".format(DATA["time"], DATA["price"]))
FILE.close()
```

I always get this error:

> File "...", line 19, in 
> FILE_STORED_DATA = FILE.readlines()[-1] IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: Right.  When you do `FILE.readlines()`, that consumes the entire contents of the file and leaves it pointed after the end.  Any additional reads will fail.  So, store the `readlines()` result in a list; then you can refer to the list elements as you wish.  And DO NOT use capital letters for variable names.  It makes your code hard to read.  All caps should be reserved for constants.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've changed your variables to lower case.  I have eliminated your simultaneous reading and writing by reading the entire contents into a list, then re-opening the file in append mode.

```
data = requests.get("...", {"...": "...", "...": "..."}).json()
current_data = "{}: {}\n".format(data["time"], data["price"])
stored_data = []

if os.path.exists("SPRIT.log"):
    with open("SPRIT.log", "r") as logfile:
        stored_data = logfile.readlines()

with open("SPRIT.log", "a") as logfile:
    if not stored_data or current_data != stored_data[-1]:
        logfile.write(current_data)
```

Comment: And unless you're using python < 3.5, you f-strings (for `current_data` is generally preferred for readability and speed.